# Make view appear gradually

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like for one of my views to appear gradually on screen and I am not sure what to use. I tried with animations and combinations of alpha and scale animations in XML, for example something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="2000"></alpha>
</set>
```

It doesn't give me expected result. I don't want my view to scale to final position, I would like it to appear gradually. It shouldn't start as small View and then becoming bigger and bigger. It should be it's original size at the beginning.

For example if revealing last's 3 second, at the beginning view would not be visible at all. At 0.1 second it would start revealing a little bit, at 1.5 second it would be revealed 50% and after 3 seconds it's revealed 100%.

Something like this:

[image]

How to accomplish that? Thanks :)

Comment: Your animation XML looks correct - it shouldn't scale at all as you're only indicating alpha... Have you tried programmatically via view.animate().alpha(1).start()?

Comment: @Berdon, I don't want it like that. It's a little bit hard to explain :) I want it to appear but 'peace by peace'. I edited my question.

Comment: if you are wanting it like gif animation, there is a very hard way to go. change duration for more piece by piece result.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an AsyncTask/ValueAnimator to update the graphics to be drawn in onDraw(Canvas) of the animated view.

in onDraw(Canvas), first draw the circle, then draw the image with paint with PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN so that only the area of the circle is shown to the screen.

I have shared a complete demo source code at [Github](https://github.com/chanpatrick320/animated-mask)

The APK is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9f85hmfN3csUmkwV0VTVW9fdWs/view?usp=sharing)

The source code of the custom view is as below:

```
package hk.patsolution.animationentrydemo;

import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by patrickchan on 22/1/15.
 */
public class CircleMaskView extends View implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
    private int radius;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint normal,clear;
    private Bitmap bitmap ,foreground;

    public CircleMaskView(Context c){
        super(c);

    }

    public CircleMaskView(Context c, AttributeSet attr){
        super(c, attr);
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        clear=new Paint();
        clear.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        normal=new Paint();
        normal.setFilterBitmap(true);

    }

    public void startAnimation(int duration){
        ValueAnimator v=ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
        v.setStartDelay(0);
        v.setDuration(duration);
        v.addUpdateListener(this);
        v.start();

    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap b){
        bitmap= b;
        foreground=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        super.onDraw(c);
        c.drawBitmap(foreground,0,0,normal);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        radius=(int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
        Canvas c=new Canvas();
        c.setBitmap(foreground);
        c.drawRect(0, 0, foreground.getWidth(), foreground.getHeight(), clear);
        c.drawCircle(this.getMeasuredWidth()/2,this.getMeasuredHeight()/2,radius*this.getMeasuredWidth()/100,normal);

        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);


        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Patrick, I just run into this thread. Can you please give a little bit more details about how to accomplish this with onDraw(Canvas)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android interpolator to xml - it would give fade in effect (image would appear gradually - no scaling):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="2000"
      />
</set>
```

Note: you can modify duration as you wish.

In code:

```
 // using fadein.xml in anim folder in resources
 final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
 // using currentImage as the image view
    currentImage.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
```

If you want fadeout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.1"
      android:duration="2000"
      />
</set>
```